# How to set up IIS as a caching web proxy?

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7, proxy

I want to set up a local proxy on my windows computer to serve as a caching proxy to speed up internet access. I have seen people use IIS for the same purpose but cannot figure out how it is done.

How would I set up IIS as a caching web proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS is not a good solution for this, It can be done, however there are many other easier to set up free alternatives you can use. [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) is one of the most popular and is free.

Comment: Yes I recommend Squid also.